# Hockeyapp doesnt send any crash report

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports, hockeyapp

I had a problem with the latest version of my app, there is no crash report (in hockeyappp panel) at all but I had seen several crashes on my device, I updated SDK and checked this doc and report:

https://www.hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/4.1.3/docs/docs/Troubleshooting-Crash-Reporting-Not-Working.html

https://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/44219-cant-submit-crash-report-macos-hockeysdk-31

but nothing changed, there is no crash report in the new fake version with throwing manual crash, my log is :

---

```
2017-05-22 14:07:00.201432+0430 MyBook[274:20890] [HockeySDK] -[BITCrashManager sendCrashReportWithFilename:xml:attachment:]/1777 INFO: Sending crash reports started.
2017-05-22 14:07:32.803691+0430 MyBook[274:20890] [HockeySDK] -[BITCrashManager processUploadResultWithFilename:responseData:statusCode:error:]_block_invoke/1681 INFO: Received API response: {
    delay = 6000;
    id = 11821670794;
    status = "-80";
}
```

*what is the meaning of this response :| , any help is appreciated

Comment: Please show code.

Comment: The response means that the server accepted the crash report. Please note that builds are assigned according to the build number and not the app version. Please contact HockeyApp support, they should surely be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contact with hockeyapp support , my problem was my Version code was increased but my build number allways is 1.0 and didn't increase and hockeyapp server is sensetive on build number :|, but I think server api should be sensetive on both version code and build number, so I change version code to 3.3 and build number with same value 3.3 and it works well :|

Comment: The next generation product of HockeyApp, which is Mobile Center, will do exactly that.