# Swift HockeyApp: Custom crash log not shown on console

Tags: swift, hockeyapp

I am exploring uploading crash log to HockeyApp but the crash log are not showing up on HockeyApp's console panel.

The format of the crash log is copied from their demo code on their [website](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api/api-crashes) as such, with modification to `Package` and `CrashReporter Key`:

```
Package: //Bundle ID as shown on HockeyApp console
Version: 1.3
OS: Mac OS X 10.14.2 (18C54)
Manufacturer: Apple
Model: MacBookPro12,1
Date: Wed Apr 24 15:35:08 GMT+08:00 2019
CrashReporter Key: //Incident key generated in the crash log

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo\{de.codenauts.hockeyapp/de.codenauts.hockeyapp.MainActivity\}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4066)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2140)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
  ...
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319120/post-custom-crashes-from-asp-net-mvc-for-hockey-app-doesnt-work) suggested that the `date` field may be wrong, but I have made adjustments from the demo code so I suppose it should be alright.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111177/hockeyapp-doesnt-send-any-crash-report) also suggested to check on the version field. The versions available on HockeyApp are as shown here, and I am targeting the version 1.3:
[image]

I have tried `1.3`, `1.3(3)`, `3` but all doesn't seem to work.

My POST request returns a `statusCode` of 201 created, so I suppose the network request is successful. Am I missing something?

**EDIT: POST function**

This is the POST function that I use to upload the custom crash report.

```
func postLog(filename: String) {
    let urlString = "https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/APP_ID/crashes/upload"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}

    guard let filepath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil) else {
        print("Filepath nil")
        return
    }

    let fileData = NSData(contentsOf: filepath)

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = createBody(parameters: [:], boundary: boundary, data: fileData! as Data, mimeType: "text/plain", filename: filename)

    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
    }

    dataTask.resume()

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is valid to add java stacktrace to an iOS crash report, I guess the statuscode 201 only means they have received the crash report and they will process it later(Then it probably fails from your description). But if you are testing the feasibility of  sending custom crash report, is it possible to download an raw iOS crash report and make the needed change(Package/Version/CrashReporterKey...) then try to send it again?

Comment: @AlickPann that was my initial attempt. I attempted to upload the crash log generated from my iPhone, but it did not get uploaded successfully. Therefore I took a step back to try out their `demo` crash report, which also did not upload successfully, and gave the same `statusCode 201`.

Comment: @Koh Hey! I work on HockeyApp. If you want, you can send us a support request with your App ID and we can  take a look at what's wrong.

Comment: @LukasSpieß ok, I have sent a support request to hockey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting HockeyApp Support, the problem was at the `createBody` function.

The `name` parameter needs to be `log` instead of `file`.

```
func createBody(parameters: [String: String],
                boundary: String,
                data: Data,
                mimeType: String,
                filename: String) -> Data {
    let body = NSMutableData()

    let boundaryPrefix = "--\(boundary)\r\n"

    for (key, value) in parameters {
        body.appendString(boundaryPrefix)
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
    }

    body.appendString(boundaryPrefix)

    //Problem was on this line, previously it was name=\"file\". After changing to log, it worked
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"log\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")

    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n")
    body.append(data)
    body.appendString("\r\n")
    body.appendString("--".appending(boundary.appending("--")))

    return body as Data
}
```